# import triggers in oracle sql developer

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL developer tool I wrote some triggers. I exported them in .sql files
I want those triggers(.sql files) to be imported on the other machine's sql developer tool.
I searched but couldn't find any solution to this.[image]

Comment: You have tagged the question `plsqldeveloper`, so If you want to "import" them to PL/SQL Developer (by Allround Automations), you should rename the files to .trg, and then click File > Open > Program File, and then double click your file. If that is not the case, then you should not tag with `plsqldeveloper`

Comment: corrected the tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAve the file in your friend machine from his sqldeveloper Go to View --> Files.
In left side you get the brower where the file your friend has saved juz open it.

[image]

Comment: I can see that sql file in my sql developer but now how do i put it in the triggers folder . e.g. as i can see in your screenshot untitled.sql. how do i put that into the Triggers folder

Comment: From Option File -->Save give the desired folder

Comment: have you opened the .sql file in your frd pc just compile it in the scheme which it want to be created and refresh in trigger folder you can find .

Comment: I had to import triggers which could not be compiled into new sql developer because they had references from previous oracle db. hence chagned the references to dummy tables and manually saved the triggers :( . any way Thanks